# How can I count total number of instructions of a function in a WebAssembly module?

Tags: module, webassembly, low-level, instructions

WebAssembly code consists of sequences of [instructions](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/instructions.html). I am looking to identify the total number of instructions of a certain function in a WebAssembly module.

Is there an existing method to easily count the total number of instructions invoked by a certain function in a WebAssembly module?

Best scenario would be a script that takes in a .wasm/.wat file and displays the number of instructions per function.

Comment: Total number of *machine* instructions after JIT for some real CPU?  Or number of WASM instructions for the virtual machine?

Comment: @PeterCordes I am referring to the number of Wasm instructions for the virtual machine.

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Given that Wasm has things like structured block instructions, you'd first need to define your exact metric anyways (e.g., do you consider `if-else` 1, 2, or 3 instructions? Each choice is reasonable).

Comment: You could do it pretty easily on .wat files by counting matched brackets since WASM is pretty Lisp-like. For .wasm files you'd just convert them to .wat first.